# Why is a bridgehead atom bearing a negative or a positive charge unstable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

Why is a bridgehead atom bearing a negative or a positive charge unstable? Is it something with the structure of bridge bonds? I am unable to understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the [answer by Aditya Dev](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/36955/5026) has already dealt with the carbocation part, I'll write about the carbanion one. The OP states that:

> Why is a bridgehead atom bearing a negative or a positive charge unstable?

This is partially incorrect. Carbanions in bridgehead position are infact stable. From March Advanced Organic Chemistry, 6th ed, Chapter 5, Carbanions:

> Carbons at bridgeheads, although extremely reluctant to undergo reactions in which they must be converted to carbocations, undergo with ease reactions in which they must be carbanions and **stable bridgehead carbanions are known.**

(my emphasis)

It also says that:

> For other evidence that carbanions are pyramidal, see Streitwieser, Jr., A.; Young, W.R. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1969, 91, 529; Peoples, P.R.; Grutzner, J.B. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1980, 102, 4709.

This makes the picture completely clear. Bridgehead carbanions are not planar, but in fact, pyramidal. So, they are **definitely**  not sp<sup>2</sup> and hence, the Bredt rule isn't violated by their being stable.

Answer (score 8):

The hybridisation of a bridgehead carbon when its not charged is sp<sup>3</sup>. Now, if you remove a hydrogen atom, its hybridisation becomes sp<sup>2</sup>.

Normally, in sp<sup>2</sup> hybridisation, the 3 hybridised orbitals lie in a single plane for minimised repulsions. But the bridgehead carbon with positive charge would not have hybridised orbitals in a single plane. This increases repulsion and makes the compound unstable.

Here is a link - [Bredt's Rule](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/09/02/bredts-rule-and-summary-of-cycloalkanes/) - that explains the same thing, but instead of a positively charged bridgehead, they discuss a double bond on the bridgehead atom.