# How will this reaction proceed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: Acidic dehydrogenation of alcohol]

Will there be a hydride shift to form a tertiary carbocation or will it proceed as secondary carbocation?

My text book shows that it would proceed as secondary carbocation
But tertiary carbocation is more stable. I am a bit confused here.
Will someone please clarify?

Comment: Depends on the reaction conditions...

Comment: Please cite the textbook.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what kind of conditions? @Zhe

Comment: Temperature, solvent, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It will surely proceed as a secondary carbocation and no hydride shift will take place. Because if hydride shift takes place, bridgehead carbon will acquire positive charge i.e. will become unstable.

For detailed explanation check this out:
[Why are bridge bonds with negative or positive charge on bridge head unstable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/36950/why-are-bridge-bonds-with-negative-or-positive-charge-on-bridge-head-unstable)